# SetExpressCheckout SOLUTIONTYPE = SOLE

Tags: paypal

I have a question regarding the ExpressCheckOut (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

One of the paremeters for the SetExpressCheckout is SOLUTIONTYPE, which can be set to "SOLE" ("Buyer does not need to create a PayPal account to check out. This is referred to as PayPal Account Optional."). I have PayPal Account Optional turned "ON". However, I noticed that this does not work for all countries, for example Brazil, Mexico. Is it possible to get a list of countries where the express checkout can be done without the need for the clients to make an account (or I am doing something wrong?).

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guest checkout is not available for every country. To confirm or verify if Brazil and Mexico is, you can submit a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts

PayPal does not publish a list of countries that has guest checkout.

Comment: Hello, you are right. PayPal does not publish the list. I got it by email them. Thank you!